# Connection failed due to Kerberos error (SQL Server connection)

Tags: macos, kerberos

I am attempting to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database using Windows Authentication (macOS, Azure Data Studio).

```
Connection failed due to Kerberos error.
Help configuring Kerberos is available at https://aka.ms/sqlopskerberos
If you have previously connected you may need to re-run kinit.
```

- I ran kinit command from terminal
- I visited the aforementioned website https://aka.ms/sqlopskerberos

  - it redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/enable-kerberos?view=sql-server-ver15
  - I went to the macOS section

This is where things got weird. It tells me to visit another site that has documentation and tells me to create a file called edu.mit.Kerberos but the original documentation says the file I need to edit is krb5.conf. I can't find either file on my mac ('using Finder').

Additionally I ran klist command and it returns my credential (so another question I have is do I even need to edit the krb5.conf file if my credential is already listed?)

In summary, how do I solve this connection failed due to kerberos error?

(side note: I had to set TrustServerCertificate to true on the connection, else it would return a different error.)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem- after running `kinit user@COMPANY.DOMAIN` and seeing my ticket in `klist`, I ran a `sudo kinit`, no user specified, in both a terminal session and the session baked into Azure Data Studio, and something about *that* finally allowed ADS to connect to my servers on the local network. I didn't see this mentioned anywhere in the documentation, but it did work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

On Mac OS X, the Kerberos v4 and v5 configuration information is saved in the edu.mit.Kerberos file. It used to hold the Kerberos Login Library and Kerberos management application preferences, but now they have their own preference files: edu.mit.Kerberos.KerberosLogin.plist and edu.mit.Kerberos.KerberosApp.plist.

This information is stored in the data fork of the edu.mit.Kerberos file, which also contains the realm and server configuration information (the info that would be found in the krb5.conf file on Unix). For additional details, see the Kerberos Configuration File Format section.

> If you don't have an edu.mit.Kerberos file, you'll need to:
>
> (/System/Library/CoreServices/Kerberos) Run the Kerberos programme.
> From the Edit menu, choose Edit Realms... Enter details about your
> site's realm in the edit realms dialogue. For further information on
> what the various fields imply, see the Kerberos Configuration section.

**Note:** While an edu.mit.Kerberos file may exist in your /Users/username/Library/Preferences directory, you should keep your configuration information in /Library/Preferences.

Please visit for additional information, see [edu.mit.Kerberos](http://web.mit.edu/macdev/KfM/Common/Documentation/preferences-osx.html) File Locations.

Comment: The information on the MIT site only applies to MacOS 10.x. We're on 12 now, and the information is no longer valid.

Comment: Please provide context information to indicate on which MacOs version this tip is working